# Is there a way to force an email received by a blackberry to open directly in a certain URL?

Tags: blackberry

Let me explain:
There are some apps (like the Facebook app) that send emails to the BB device, but when I open the said email, it opens directly in my facebook app. How is that possible? Is there an API or something I need to know about to be able to program that on my own app?

On another topic, could I do the same thing, but simply force the email to open a certain url in the BB browser?

Hope I explained myself.

Cheers!

Comment: It is not an "e-mail"
Applications can put their messages to messages folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

Take a look at the Message List Demo Sample application and the [net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/package-summary.html).* apis. That will handle the "injecting my own stuff into the message list" component of what Facebook does.

Secondly as for "grabbing incoming emails and doing things with them" you need to use FolderListener from [net.rim.blackberry.api.mail](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mail/package-summary.html).* APIs